# Linq strange behavior

Tags: c#, linq

Statment:

```
(definitions != null && definitions.Where(key => key.asset_id != null &&
                                          key.asset_id == item).FirstOrDefault() != null
```

Throws:

> collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute

How to fix this?

```
if (definitions != null 
    && definitions
         .Where(key => key.asset_id != null && key.asset_id == item)
         .FirstOrDefault() != null)
{
    CurrentDuration = definitions
                        .Where(key => key.asset_id != null && key.asset_id == item)
                        .FirstOrDefault().duration;
}
```

Comment: are you running this inside any loop?

Comment: This part is inside function DrawBox(), and this function is inside foreach.Yes.

Comment: It wiil be toooo big.

Comment: In general, if you modify a IList, you cannot continue to execute the loop.

Comment: Well, something is modifying your definitions collection on the fly and that breaks the foreach. Without seeing that loop it's impossible to suggest changes, but you could store your intended changes to collection in a variable or dictionary, and then implement them after loop has been completed.

Comment: You should start with using variables. You are executing the LINQ query multiple times.

Comment: Don't be scared to try and interpret the exception yourself. `collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute` -  from the relevant code you're posted, the only 'collection' is `definitions`. That collection is being modified (you know what modified means) thus the enumeration ('loop') may not execute ('continue'). i.e. Something in your code is modifying that collection while it loops over it. Since I trust the exception more than your question, I'd suggest you've omitted important code from your example. I'm going to assume that within your `foreach` you're setting something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that somewhere in your code the `definitions` collection is modified. Mostly it's because of collection modification in another thread, but it could have some other reasons. You should find out the piece of code which is modifying collection somewhere else. You can protect the `definitions` variable using a `lock` wherever you're using `definitions`.

```
if (definitions != null)
{
    lock (definiitons)
    {
        var definition = definitions.FirstOrDefault(key => key.asset_id != null && key.asset_id == item);
        if (definition != null)
            CurrentDuration = definition.duration;
    }
}
```

and put lock everywhere you're modifying the `definitions` or its references, for example:

```
lock (definitions)
{
    definitions.Add(x);
}
```

or

```
lock (definitions)
{
    definitions.Remove(x);
}
```

or even

```
var otherRef = definitions
lock (otherRef )
{
    otherRef .Add(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that "CurrentDuration" is a foreach loop variable counter.

The foreach statement is used to iterate through the collection to get the information that you want, but can not be used to add ,remove or change items from the source collection to avoid unpredictable side effects. If you need to add, remove or change items from the source collection, use a for loop.